# How to calculate total of a column per group?

Tags: google-sheets

How can I generate the `Total` column from the below screenshot?

As you can probably see, it's a total of all of the `Quantity` values for a given `Order number`. From which I can derive `Proportion`, and that part's nice and simple once `Total` is filled.

I think there's probably a simple solution but I can't my head around it.

[image: Order/Quantity/Total/Proportion]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try:

```
=sumif(A:A,A2,B:B)
```

in C2 and copy down to suit.

Comment: SUMIF reference: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583?hl=en

Comment: Thanks, that negates the `VLOOKUP` even being necessary as well